# .htaccess file causing site to go 403

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Why would a blank .htaccess file cause a site to go 403? It works fine in subdirectories, but if I put an .htaccess file in the public root of my site, it goes 403.

Comment: do you have an index file in you root?

Comment: Yes, there is a .php index file.

Comment: check CHMOD ... no reason for that errror ... something is missing or it is not accessible - 403 error

Comment: But why would it happen if the file is blank, shouldn't it have no effect in that case?

Comment: Yup, the host has something wrong, all new files are being created with broken owner and groups. I guess the 403 was the result of the webserver not being able to read the .htaccess file, in which case it seems like an Apache bug. At least now I know how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: It is not a bug ... Apache shows that the file is not acessible - that's why you have 403 error :)